# Conditional formatting is applied (without errors) but sheet doesn't update until I manually go to 'Edit Rules'

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

Conditional formatting is applied (without errors) but sheet doesn't update until I manually go to 'Edit Rules'.

I'm using the `formula` value for `value` parameter. The formula is correct. I verified it first by entering it in Excel; and, this is not generating any error, either.

```
ws.conditional_format(1, 0, total_rows, total_columns,
                      {'type'     : 'formula',
                       'criteria' : '=XOR(ISERR(FIND("text1",LOWER($F2))),ISERR(FIND("text2",LOWER($F2))))',
                       'format'   : format1})
```

It's just that I have to go to 'Manage Rules', then edit the rule, and then press OK in the 'Edit Rule' dialog box for it to work. I tried shifting this part of code before writing the cells to the sheet using `write_row`, but that doesn't help either.

Other portions of code that might be relevant:

```
total_rows = len(data) - 1
total_columns = len(data[0]) - 1
format1 = wb.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE', 'font_color': '#9C0006'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel 2010 and later added functions which weren't defined in the original file specification.

These functions are referred to by Microsoft as future functions. Examples of these functions are `ACOT`, `CHISQ.DIST.RT` , `CONFIDENCE.NORM`, `STDEV.P`, `STDEV.S` and `WORKDAY.INTL`. And also, in this case, `XOR`.

In order to get them to work you need to prefix the formula with `_xlfn.`. Like this:

```
'criteria': '=_xlfn.XOR(ISERR(FIND("text1",LOWER($F2))),ISERR(FIND("text2",LOWER($F2))))',
```

The prefix doesn't show up in Excel.

See the [following section of the XlsxWriter docs on Working with Formulas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formulas-added-in-excel-2010-and-later).